# 6 millions of spatial data in MapBox?

Tags: python, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I have a csv that contains **6 millions of spatial data**.

Recently while searching over the internet i found [here](https://blog.mapbox.com/clustering-millions-of-points-on-a-map-with-supercluster-272046ec5c97) and also [here](https://blog.getwemap.com/toujours-plus-de-points-sur-ma-carte-9992099267aa) that i can plot my spatial data very easy and fast on a mapbox using [supercluster algorithme](https://github.com/mapbox/supercluster) by just Loading a **geojson file**.

i m using *python*  so i searched and i found [pysupercluster](https://github.com/wemap/pysupercluster)

but i didn't understand for the moment how to use it ! any helps?

Comment: Hey, we would love to help you, but it is difficult to do so without knowing specifics of what you have already tried. Can you post some code showing your previous attempt?

Comment: actually i m blocked on how to use pysupercluster since there is no clear documentation about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Algorithme used for clustring mapbox markers is **SuperCluster**.